# Symfony routing URL works but its wrong

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have the following I have the following settings at routing.yml:

```
show_collection:
  url:   /:module/collection/:collection
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
  param: { module: collection, action: showcollection }

collection:
  url:   /collection/
  param: { module: collection, action: index }
```

The link works correctly, however with one problem. The link is this:

```
frontend_dev.php/collection/showcollection/collection/{name of collection}
```

So it's making /module/action/module/name_of_collection.
What I needed was:

```
 frontend_dev.php/collection/showcollection/{name of collection}
```

It would make a lot more sense even though it works as it is now. I already looked at jobeet and other routing tutorials, however I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Heres the url_for:

```
url_for(array(
      'module' => 'collection',
      'action' => 'showcollection',
      'collection' => $collection->getName()
))
```

This is the result:

```
  .../collection/showcollection/collection/{collection Name}
```

Comment: And how would it work if you change the `show_collection url` to `/:module/:collection`? Wouldn't fit your needs?

Comment: Well, it does the same thing. And the url is actually working in two different ways. The way I described and the way I want. However I'm not beeing able to get tue url_for or the link_to to construct the link how I want.

Comment: Why aren't you able to use `url_for` or `link_to`? Maybe there's the problem :(

Comment: Well, I already updated the route... I'm trying different solutions like passing the ID instead of the collection name.

Comment: Did you remove the generic routing rules from the file? Also have a look at @pfefferle's answer and it should work.

Comment: Nope, the default ones are still there! I believe that's the normal case since they are needed for the "general" routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the route to:

```
show_collection:
  url:   /:module/:action/:collection
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
  param: { module: collection, action: showcollection }
```

and use

```
url_for('@show_collection?collection='.$collection->getName());
```